# Flutter: Can I force flutter to install packages from pubspec.lock?

Tags: flutter, dart, continuous-integration

Does anyone know if you can do reproducible builds in Flutter? There doesn't seem to be an option to install from the `pubspec.lock` file. I would of expected something like:

`flutter pub get --from-lockfile`

The problem is that the `pubspec.lock` is modified on every run of `flutter pub get` so I can't easily go back to the previous state of the dependencies at different points in the git history.

I would of expected it to behave like the [yarn.lock](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/yarn-lock/) or [package-lock.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/configuring-npm/package-lock-json.html) which allow you to create reproducible builds of the project.

Comment: `pub get` *should* already do this within reason according to the [docs](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd/pub-get)

Comment: Yes, if the alleged behavior can be reproduced with a minimal example using `pub get` from the Dart SDK, please file an issue here: https://github.com/dart-lang/pub

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [doc](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd/pub-get), `pub get` should fetch what's in `pubspec.lock` if the lockfile contains the solution for the dependency requirements and constraints configured in `pubspec.yaml`. Simply put, if `pubspec.yaml` and `pubspec.lock` isn't modified, and neither Dart nor Flutter SDK is upgraded, then `pub get` should fetch what's listed in `pubspec.lock`.

If you're still having issues and can be reproducible, you can file an issue here https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues - as jonasfj also mentioned in the Comments.

Comment: The key for me was "**and neither Dart nor Flutter SDK is upgraded**". I always have trouble with reproducibility when checking out an old commit. Downgrading to the previous Flutter version before running `flutter pub get` does the trick.